# Parse error for json response in jquery tokenizer

Tags: jquery, json, tokenize

I used jquery multi select tokenizer jquery plugin from https://www.zellerda.com/projects/jquery/tokenize. I am developing a mail service in php between parents and teachers.When a parent type teachername,it needs to come in dropdown and on clicking it ,it needs to be in the textbox.When I type teachername,the console is showing parse error.When I check response,I am getting json array.Please help me.

Jquery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/jquery_multipleSelect/jquery.tokenize.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery_multipleSelect/jquery.tokenize.js">
</script>

$('#to_message').tokenize({
    datas: "module/parents/communication/view_teacher_search.php?action=new_message",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",//not working when commented
    //dataType: "json",//without commented also not working
    autosize: true,
    nbDropdownElements: 30,
    onAddToken: function(value, text, e){
        $( "#compose_message" ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="teacher_ids[]" id="'+value+'" value="'+value+'" >' );
    },
    onRemoveToken: function(value, e){
        $( "#"+value ).remove();
    }
});
```

**view_teacher_search.php**

```
 $db->query($getStudentsListQuery);
//$selStudents = '';
    while($row = $db->get_row())
   {                    
    $data .=   ' {
                    "text" : "' .$row[1] . ' - '. $row[2] .' - ['. $row[3] .']",
                    "value" : "'.$row[0].'"
                },';
    if($action == 'reply_message'){
        break;    
    }
   } 
  $new_userdata = substr_replace($data,"",-1); 
  echo '[ '. $new_userdata .' ]';
```

[image: SCreen shot]

**EDIT:**Should I need to make the response inside  component??

Comment: The backslash \ needs to be escaped \\

Comment: Can you answer the comment as answer.I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that every single literal backslash needs to be escaped using another backslash

\ becomes \\

```
"text" : "Abdul Hakim - Hamed - [Language and literature \\ Arabic]",
```